# Cannot add `margin` to `<legend>` element in Safari & Chrome (WebKit)

Tags: html, css, webkit, legend

**EDIT**: As of 2012-06-11 this bug has been finally fixed! https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35981#c1

I have some pretty straightforward markup:

```
<form action="">
    <fieldset class="compact">                  
        <legend>Member Tools</legend>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text"/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I am attempting to add a small margin to the bottom of the `legend` element, this works just fine in Firefox 2 and 3 as well as IE 5-8, however in Safari and Chrome adding a `margin` does nothing. As far as I know `legend` is just another block level element and Webkit should have no issue adding a `margin` to it, or am I incorrect?

Comment: Google can get Quake II working in HTML 5 on Safari and Chrome. And yet I too struggle with CSS anomalies. The ironies in the client-side world never cease to amaze me. http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/04/look-ma-no-plugin.html

Comment: Over two years old and still not addressed! https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35981

Comment: This issue still exists within the latest Windows version (5.1.7), released in May 2012. Apple no longer continues to develop Safari for Windows - so don't expect a fix, ever.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a bit of research I found a work-around for this that I believe to be the least "hacky" method for solving it. Using the nasty webkit targeting hacks really weren't an option, but I found that the `-webkit-margin-collapse: separate` property seems to work in stopping the margins on the elements from collapsing just as it describes.

So in my scenario the following fixes the issue by adding a margin to the top of the first label element (right below the legend) in the fieldset:

```
fieldset > label:first-of-type
{
-webkit-margin-top-collapse: separate;
margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Not perfect, but better than nothing, other browsers should just collapse the margins normally.

If anyone is curious someone actually did file a bug report about this # 35981

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35981

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: What do you think about this solution? `legend + label { -webkit-margin-top-collapse: separate; margin-top: 3px; }` It should be more generic and have a wider browser support (CSS2 instead of CSS3)

Answer (score 6):

Well, `<legend>` really *isn't* "just another block-level element."  Maybe it should be, but the fact is that it inherently is going to have layout peculiarities in that it's supposed to do something pretty weird, as elements go.  Between IE and Firefox, the effects of margin and padding on `<legend>` elements are a lot different.

Do you want to just separate `<fieldset>` content from the top of the box?  If so, I'd try playing with `padding-top` of the fieldset itself.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Going back and trying to find it in the spec I can't actually tell what it's supposed to be, whatever I set display to has no effect.

I would try and adjust the padding of the fieldset, but I'm looking to increase the distance between the bottom of the legend and the first label.

Comment: Well, `<legend>` is one of those throwbacks to yesteryear. That you can style  it *at all* is kind-of amazing :-)  I have some styled-up fieldsets in my own app, and I plan to re-do those with plain old `<div>` blocks at some point so that I can clean up some browser differences (mostly about horizontal positioning, but it's the same sort of problem).

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to post an answer to such an old thread, but there's actually a pretty easy solution for this that doesn't require any hacks. All you need to do is add padding to the top of your `fieldset` element.

```
fieldset { padding: 10px 0 0; }
```

This might make what I'm trying to say a little more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/8fyvY/

Comment: this padding works differently in IE8 and 7. It puts the padding above the legend.

Comment: So weird. Given that the legend is inside the fieldset, wouldn't it make more sense for the padding to be applied above the legend as ie7 and 8 do?

Comment: Beats me. I stumbled up on this solution purely on accident.

Comment: Good idea in theory, but if you have more than one `<legend>` tag in a `<fieldset>` then you still wont get the desired results.

Comment: Should one `<fieldset>` element not only have one `<legend>` at maximum?

Comment: @Nic: the [HTML 4 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) and [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element) are even stricter: a `<legend>` can exist as the first child of a `<fieldset>`, and that's all (though the HTML5 description of `<fieldset>` states "The name of the group is given by the first legend element that is a child of the fieldset element, if any", which can be read to mean that later `<legend>`s are ignored).

Answer (score 4):

Ive just found adding a 1px padding to the fieldset seems to make it suddenly aware of the margins it contains (the spacing created is more than 1 px).

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem and everything look fine on chrome but safari make the problem. 
In that case if I add this code

```
fieldset > legend:first-of-type
{
-webkit-margin-top-collapse: separate;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

I get double margin on Chrome. Then just decide to do the following

```
fieldset > legend + *{
    padding-top:3px;
}
```

Hope that help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To get a legend working with bottom border and margin in all browsers I insert a span inside the legend, put the border on the span, set the legend margin to 0 and add padding to the bottom of the legend.

e.g.

```
legend {
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

legend span {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f0ebe6;
}
```