# Webkit / Blink browsers not respecting display styling on legend tag

Tags: html, css, webkit, blink

Legend Tags in Webkit browsers seem not to accept any styling besides `block` and `none` for the `CSS` `display` property:

Here's the HTML

```
<legend>I should display as an inline block</legend>
<div>I should be on the same line</div>
```

And here's the CSS (put anything other than `block` or `none` as `display` style)

```
legend {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    -webkit-margin-top-collapse: separate;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

As you [can see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhNbd/2/), the legend tag will always be styled as a block.

[image]

You will also see that despite I applied `-webkit-margin-top-collapse: separate`, [which lets one apply margins to legend tags in webkit despite a quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339161/legend-tag-and-chrome), the problem still persists.

I reckon this is a bug although it does not appear in the [list of bugs when searching for legend](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=legend), but does anyone know how to circumvent it?

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is to your actual issue, but `<legend>` is only valid markup as the first child of a `<fieldset>` element (and is rendered as the "header" of that element) - which will obey the `display: inline-block;` rule, even in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/vhNbd/3/ - It is also possible to float the `<legend>` element. That said, I agree that it indeed does look like a bug, or at least a webkit quirk.

Comment: @xec You're right, but if you put the div as a sibling inside the fieldset like so http://jsfiddle.net/vhNbd/5/, the `legend` behaves like a `block` again. Posted a [bug report here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116031)

Comment: Yes, exactly (hence the "no effect in chrome" comment). A minor note about the bug report comment though: floating the element *does not make it accept inline-block* (it just floats, removing the display property when it is floating will have no effect).

Comment: @xec I looked up the Computed styles in the inspector, if a float is applied the display property there is the one defined in the css. Hence my bug report comment. But I see what you mean and you're absolutely right, the element is just floated and therefore behaving the way it is.

Comment: That is odd, in my Chrome (Version 26.0.1410.64 m / win8) **Computed styles** still says `display: block;` =/

Comment: @xec Chromium 28.0.1497.0 on osx here does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the legend and div to go side by side with the following CSS.

```
legend {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    float:left;
}
div {
    display: inline;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhNbd/4/

Comment: Thanks, the only downside is though that with a floated element `vertical-align` won't work.

Comment: I'm assuming the answer here is "no" but are you able to use an element other than `legend`?

Comment: I was thinking of that too, since I use a form generation engine (formtastic on rails), it would be a shame and a lot of work to break the semantics just for styling reasons. Meanwhile I will try to float the element and style it, but I'm still hoping for that magic `-webkit-anything` property letting me get a hold of `legend`'s display style.

Comment: You could try going the jQuery/JavaScript route. Try using jQuery `wrap()` and wrap a `span` (or some other element) around the `legend`. Here's my updated jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/vhNbd/7/

Comment: Appreciate the help! I'd rather not use javascript / jQuery though. But wrapping the element could be a workaround, as `formtastic` lets me write extensions.