# asp:Panel grouping text and borders are not displayed using chrome/IE10

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, panel, asp.net-3.5, internet-explorer-10

I want to use asp:Panel in chrome:

my code is simple:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLoginErrorMessage" runat="server" style="height:50px; Width:100%;" GroupingText="Panel">
                <asp:TextBox id="tbLoginMessage" onFocus="blur();" style="Width:100%;" TextMode="MultiLine" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" ReadOnly="true" Wrap="true" runat="Server" />

</asp:Panel>
```

The result in chrome looks like:
[image]

The grouping text is not displayed and there are no panel borders.
It happens in IE10 too (without compatiblity mode).

WHY?

Answer (score 1):

The asp:Panel's GroupingText property [is rendered using the FIELDSET and LEGEND elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.groupingtext.aspx).

There are known issues with the LEGEND tag in Chrome: [legend tag and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339161/legend-tag-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Find the `"Site.css"` file in your solution and change the `"fieldset"` class as per your requirement. 
Be aware that this change will have effects application-wide.

```
fieldset {
display: block;
border: 1px solid grey !important;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
}
fieldset legend {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue: our solution was to use LiteralControl with fieldset and legend directly...

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you have a problem you can  [Ask your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).