# Strange behavior from bootstrap with element immediately following legend

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using Twitter's bootstrap 3.0 and have a div immediately following a `<legend>` inside of a `<form>`.

The weird thing is that when I change the margin top of this div, it actually moves the legend up and down (with reference to the enclosing `<form>` tag in Chrome.

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates the effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/aq5T7/2/

You'll notice the second item the legend is moved down 50 pixels instead of the div below it.

And in the third item the legend is moved up 50 pixels instead of the div above it.

Is there anyway to change the margin of the item immediately following the legend *without* having it affect the location of the legend?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue with legend and webkit and not really related to bootstrap. Add this to your css:

```
legend, fieldset {
    -webkit-margin-collapse: separate;
}
```

You can see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339161/legend-tag-and-chrome) for more info.

Comment: Looks like this does indeed work! Here's the fiddle with the css hack added in; it fixes it completely: http://jsfiddle.net/r4KJh/