# <legend> tag accepts width if inline

Tags: html, css

When I apply the following styling to a legend tag

```
display: inline;
width: 300px;
```

I see that the legend tag has a width of `300px` It still accepts the width. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aqaacr6y/) is a demo. Is there something special with this element, because I expect inline elements to ignore the `width` setting!

Comment: The width does not actually affect the width of the element, tr increasing it in debugger and you will see nothing happens

Comment: @Huangism the width increases in Chrome

Comment: Ok well it doesn't in FF

Comment: Open the dev tools and look at the `<legend>`'s computed style. It is ignoring your styling for 'display' and still rendering as `display: block;` I'm using chrome.

Comment: Apparently the `legend` tag has other issues in webkit browsers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339161/legend-tag-and-chrome

Comment: to size a legend and make it cross browser is a mythe ;) . It is a form element and if some can be partially restyled they are not really suppose to be for many reason : depends on browser / security, remember it can send datas and files.

Comment: I haven't checked in IE but I suspect this is a webkit only issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a case similar to `button` elements, as described in [Bindings](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#bindings):

> [**10.5.2 - The `button` element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-button-element-0)
>
> ```css
> @namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
> button { binding: button; }
> ```
>
> When the *button* binding applies to a [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) element, the
>   element is expected to render as an 'inline-block' box rendered as a
>   button whose contents are the contents of the element.

Chrome seems to do the same for `legend` elements.

But probably it shouldn't be doing that, because

- The spec doesn't define such binding for `legend` elements.
- `legend` elements shouldn't be replaced elements (they are [listed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#non-replaced-elements) in the [Non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#non-replaced-elements) section), so they should conform to CSS rules.